# Adapting the SVG of a Phoenician letter for a HTML site

Tags: html, css, svg, viewbox, alphabet

I'm trying to adapt an [open-source SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waw_(letter)#/media/File:Phoenician_waw.svg) created in Inkscape so it can be embedded on [my experimental website](https://www.tomdimino.com/) in the same I've done so with other SVGs from the same alphabet.

### Phoenician "mem" and "nun" SVGs on my site

```
            <svg version="1.1" id="nūn" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-244 364 46.9 65"
                style="enable-background:new -244 364 46.9 65;" xml:space="preserve" class="symbol" title="nūn">
                <g id="layer1">
                    <path id="rect3131" d="M-238,365.1l-4.8,36.3l35.8-15.9l-2.6,41.9l8,0.5l3.4-55.2l-34.7,15.6l2.9-22.2L-238,365.1z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>

            <svg version="1.1" id="mēm" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-248.3 359 55.6 73.8"
                style="enable-background:new -248.3 359 55.6 73.8;" xml:space="preserve" class="symbol" title="mēm">
                <g id="path2220">
                    <path d="M-203.5,431.4l-6.8-4.2c7.1-11.5,9.7-22.3,8-32.8l-3.6-12l-10.5,18.8l-7-19.1l-8.7,18.1l-14.9-30.9l7.2-3.5
                        l7.7,16l9.8-20.2l7.5,20.5l11.2-20l9.3,30.8C-192.3,405.5-195.2,418.1-203.5,431.4z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
```

What's eluding me the most in adapting this "waw" SVG is the following:

- The "waw" had no defined viewbox except for width and height, which seems quite different from the viewboxes for the "mem" and "nun", e.g. "-248.3 359 55.6 73.8".
- When I try substituting my own viewbox for "waw", the "waw" simply fails to load on my page.

### The rewritten "waw" as I tried it

```
<svg version="1.1" id="waw" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-251.1 354.8 60.4 83.5"
                 style="enable-background:new -251.1 354.8 60.4 83.5;" xml:space="preserve" class="symbol" title="waw">
                <g id="layer1">
                    <path id="rect2726" 
                          d="M 19.421875,5.015625 L 13.953125,10.890625 L 38.453125,33.734375 L 38.453125,79.984375 L 46.453125,79.984375 
                             L 46.453125,33.984375 L 71.046875,11.046875 L 65.609375,5.203125 L 42.609375,26.640625 L 19.421875,5.015625 z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
```

**How should I go about rewriting this SVG so that it uses the right viewbox (relative to "mem" and "nun")?**

Comment: The orignal from Wikipedia shows `width="85" height="85"` removing width/height and adding `viewbox="0 0 85 85"` seems to work for me. `0 0` = `x y` and `85 85` = `width height`. [Wikipedia waw](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/Phoenician_waw.svg). Presumably the same should work for mem and nun.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded it up in an SVG editor ([Boxy SVG](https://boxy-svg.com/) is my favourite) to align the path with the viewbox and clean it up.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 60.4 83.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 7.122 4.266 L 1.653 10.141 L 26.153 32.984 L 26.153 79.234 L 34.153 79.234 L 34.153 33.234 L 58.747 10.297 L 53.309 4.453 L 30.309 25.891 L 7.122 4.266 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<path id="rect2726" 
      d="M 19.421875,5.015625 L 13.953125,10.890625 
         L 38.453125,33.734375 L 38.453125,79.984375 L 46.453125,79.984375 
         L 46.453125,33.984375 L 71.046875,11.046875 L 65.609375,5.203125 
         L 42.609375,26.640625 L 19.421875,5.015625 z"/>
```

I copied your path in my favorite Path editor: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#

Reduced it to 0 precision

Converted the path to relative notation (so positioning can easily be done with first **m x y** : `m7 1`)

Corrected the viewBox (calculated by the SVG path editor)

Removed the `xmlns` *NameSpace*, because modern browsers know what to do with an `<svg>` tag

Created a StackOverflow Snippet with that **[<>]** button in the SO editor, for immediate display

```css
svg { background:pink }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 135 77">
  <path d="m7 1-5 6 24 23 0 46 8 0 0-46 25-23-5-6-23 22-24-22z">
</svg>
```